# Is it possible to demagnetize side cutters with this passive magnetize/demagnetizer?

Tags: tools

I keep little neodymium magnets on my precision screwdrivers and I inadvertently touched them to my side cutters which are now weakly magnetized.

I only have a passive magnetize/demagnetize block which I use on screwdrivers but I can't seem to make it work on the side cutters, maybe because of its shape.

Is it possibly to demagnetize my side cutters this way or do I need to buy a degausser?

I'm using these to trim the leads off of electronic components. Because tiny pieces can get stuck to the jaws, subsequent trimmings cut at an odd angle can cause a rogue piece to jettison in a random direction. After every trim I have to swipe my fingers along the edges to brush them away but I'm not always successful and it can also leave a shallow slice if I'm not careful.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you are concerned about the side cutters being slightly magnetized? Those cutters are specifically marked as for use with copper wire. Copper wire should not be affected by copper wire.

Comment: Easy as competently using one of the old magnetic tape degaussers sold by Radio Shack for $15 back in the day.  Hold it up to the tool, push the button, and slowly separate them til they're at arms length.   You need 10 seconds with the tool, find a friend with one.

Comment: I've updated my answer to specify that I'm using them to trim electronic components.

Comment: you can pull off the rubber handles and bake it at 250F for 15 mins to demagnetize it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement as defined by this network.

Answer (score 0):

Use a soldering gun - while it's on, put the side-cutter next to the tip or the transformer and slowly move it away. You should feel the cutter vibrate slightly from the powerful alternating magnetic field, which works as well as a tape demagnetizer.